# database timestamp

Tags: database, timestamp

What's the definition of timestamp?
The timestamp is just for a transaction? ( no matter what actions in the transaction. The timestamp is always the time when the transaction happened.)
OR the timestamp is for each action of a transaction? (each action has a timestamp.)
[image]

For instance, when first R1(X) happened, it has a timestamp TS. But for the second R1(X), the timestamp is same with the TS? OR the timestamp has changed?

For another example, if I have *R1(X)W2(X)W1(X)*, is it view serializable? and is it conflict serializable?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably depend on which database you are using.

For SQL Server the timestamp is retrieved by using GetDate() which returns the current **database** system timestamp.

So if you insert a row using GetDate to input the timestamp, then 2 seconds later in the same transaction insert another row calling GetDate again, the second call will return a time 2 seconds later.